# How can I see the remote a branch points to, after issuing `gh pr checkout 1234`?

Tags: git, github

using the `gh` tool, if i issue `gh pr checkout 1234`, it creates a branch that has an "implicit" remote that doesn't show up in remotes.

How can i see what remote the branch is pointing to from the terminal?

---

Normally, adding a local branch that tracks a remote called `user` creates the following entry in `.git/config`

```
[remote "user"]
    url = https://github.com/user/repo
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/user/*
[branch "branch"]
    remote = user
    merge = refs/heads/branch
```

which is visible as to what the tracking branch is via `git branch -vv` and `git remote -v`

However `gh pr checkout 1234` creates the following entry in `.git/config`

```
[branch "branch"]
    remote = https://github.com/user/repo.git
    merge = refs/heads/branch
```

and `git remote -v` and `git b -vv` do not indicate that `branch` actually points to a different remote.

Is there any way to surface or query for what remote the branch actually points to?

I don't want to accidentally push commits to branches that belong to different remote repositories.

Answer (score 0):

looks like .git/config is my best bet, `git branch -vv` only works for explicit remotes.

```
git config --get-regexp "branch\..+\.remote"
```

or

```
git config --get-regexp "branch\.$(git branch --show-current)\.remote"
```